# How to remove a UIView which i added

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when the following event gets executed, i initialize and call a `UIImageView`.
Later on i will remove this view. My code is as follows;

```
self.myView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 460)];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.myView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];

[self.tableView addSubview:self.myView];
```

At a later instance i will remove the view, and my code for removing is as follows;

```
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.myView];
[self.myView setHidden:YES];
[self.myView removeFromSuperview];
```

The problem i am having is that, the view that i added to the tableview, is not getting removed. I need to know why this is hapenning, and a programatic solution to solve it.

note: i have debugged, and the remove part of the code gets executed but nothing gets removed. Help

Comment: Do you still have a problem if you don't set hidden = YES?

Comment: Have you added more than one instance of your UIView to the table? After you remove it, print out the subviews of the table view to see what children views are left.

Comment: Is self.myView nil when you call remove...?  This would result in a no-op.

Comment: How do i check if `self.myView` exist before removing it ?

Comment: By comparing it against `nil`  ... `if(self.myView == nil)`

Comment: You could use an if, but that won't remove it. I'd use `NSLog( @"%@", self.myView );` which will print out `nil` if it is bad, and a bunch of UIView info if it is a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

you should try only  `[self.myView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Why? What will that do different from what she has?

Answer (score 0):

A common issue that can cause behavior like this is modifying UIKit objects (like `UIView`s) from a background thread.  UIKit is not generally threadsafe and calls from background threads will often not change the visible state of your app for a long time, if at all.

What is the method that executes your second block of code and how does it get called?

FWIW, `bringSubviewToFront:` and `setHidden:` should be unnecessary; `removeFromSuperview` should be all that is required to remove your view.

Answer (score 0):

Was wondering if there is another controller on top of your tableview like a navigationcontroller. Would removeFromSuperview actually refer to it giving an unwanted result?